# Class does not name a type

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to make B+ tree 
and this is indexNode implementation

```
#ifdef INDEX_NODE
#define INDEX_NODE 

#include "leafNode.h"

class indexNode : public node{
   private:
       std::map<int,indexNode*> childNodes;
       std::map<int,leafNode*> leafNodes;
       int childNode_size;
       bool isLeaf;
   public:
       indexNode(int size);
       ~indexNode();
       bool getLeafCheck();
       void setLeafCheck(bool isLeaf);
       indexNode* getSubTree(int key);
}

#endif
```

C++ code above is "indexNode.h"

```
#include "indexNode.h"

indexNode::indexNode(int size): node(size){
     childNode_size = size + 1;
     isLeaf = false;
}

indexNode::~indexNode(){

}

bool indexNode::getLeafCheck(){
     return isLeaf;
}

void setLeafCheck(bool isLeaf){
    this -> isLeaf = isLeaf; 
} 

indexNode* getSubtree(int key){
   return childNodes.find(key) -> second; 
}
```

and code above is indexNode.cc

However when I try to complie this the 
g++ -c -Wall indexNode.cc
indexNode.cc:3:1: error: ‘indexNode’ does not name a type

this kind of error occur
how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should change #ifdef INDEX_NODE to #ifndef INDEX_NODE. Otherwise the class definition will be hidden by the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after the class definition.

```
} // need ;

#endif
```

Also, as Lewis mentioned, the header guard needs to be `ifndef` not `ifdef`.